# Is Zoom video conferencing tool on-topic for superuser?

Tags: support, tags, site-recommendation

I saw a tag but only linked to 4 questions. If not this site, where please? I am trying to find out more to help connect older and more vulnerable people in our village during isolation!

Comment: If your question is about “connecting older users” then that question is out of scope.  If your question is about Corvid-19 it’s probably out of scope.

Answer (score 5):

It is only on-topic where the problem is with or in using the desktop PC based client.

If your problem is with the Android application then there would be [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) or for Apple devices you could ask at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com). Otherwise for the web chat (in your browser) version it could be asked at [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

If your problem is in setting up an account or payment, then you should contact Zoom technical support directly.

Comment: This cross-device sort of tool doesn't seem to have a particularly good fit because in many cases my question might be agnostic if I'm PC/iOS. I suppose then I can phrase it for a given device and post appropriately?

Comment: Yes, you need to be specific and ask a question about the platform that is currently giving you problems on the site that is relevant at that moment. The general Zoom infrastructure and inner workings would probably be off-topic everywhere, and the fallback would be their technical support.